# Using a C++ Library in a C Project causes a long list of errors

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, gcc, mingw

I have a **C Project** which uses a **C++ library**. However, if i compile the C Project i get a long list of *"undefined reference to XY"* errors.

Those errors are caused by C++ references:

**Errors while compiling:**

```
In function `<c function>':
implicit declaration of function `<function>'
[...]
```

*(list shorted)*
Where *<c function>* is the calling function from C Project and *<function>* the function from the C++ library.

**Errors while linking:**

```
undefined reference to `std::cerr'
undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
[...]
undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
more undefined references to `__gxx_personality_v0' follow
```

*(lots of errors - example shorted)*

In the static C++ library my types / functions are enclosed by `extern "C"` block:

```
#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

    void example();

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

To ensure this, all the `#include`'s referring to C++ library are surrounded by such a `extern "C"` block too.

**Compiler:** The *C++ library* is compiled using **g++**, the *C project* using **gcc** - both from **MinGW**.

**CL (Linking):** `gcc -L<search-path here> -shared [...] -lstdc++ -l<C++ library set here>`

*Please note the `-lstdc++` flag.*

**Note:**

- The C project contains only `.c` and `.h` files – no `.cpp`
- Putting a "dummy" cpp file in like stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376966/using-c-c-static-libraries-from-iphone-objectivec-apps) didn't work
- MinGW and Eclipse CDT Indigo
- The C++ Library has a name like `lib<NAME>.a` - it's linked with `-l<NAME>`, search path is set.

---

---

## Edit:

Using `g++` as linker: `undefined reference to` std::cerr'` etc. are gone, but i get another list of errors:

```
Warning: .drectve `-aligncomm:"___hexdig_D2A",5' unrecognized
undefined reference to `<function / class / method from C++ Library>'
[...]
undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
[...]
undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
more undefined references to `__gxx_personality_v0' follow
undefined reference to `__chkstk_ms'
[...]
```

*(list shorted)*

eg. `_Unwind_Resume` is available in `nm` of the c++ library.

---

## Example:

This part is in the Library (C++):

**Test.h** - Header

```
#ifndef TEST_H_
#define TEST_H_

// --- Pure C++ here ---
#ifdef __cplusplus

#include <string>     /* (1) */
class Test
{
public:
    Test();
    
    
    void aMethod();
    
private:
    int i;
};
#endif

// --- Mixed (C / C++ ) here ---

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
   
    extern void doTest();
    extern void invoke();
    
#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* TEST_H_ */
```

**Test.cpp** - Implementation of C++ part

```
#include "Test.h"


Test::Test() : i(0) { }

void Test::aMethod()
{
    this->i++;
}


void invoke()
{
    Test i;
    i.aMethod();
}
```

**Test.c** - Implementation of C Interface (still in library!)

```
#include "Test.h"

void doTest()
{
    invoke();
}
```

Now, here comes the part of the second project (pure C):

```
#include "Test.h"


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    doTest();
    
    return 0;
}
```

**`(1)`**: If i remove that include i can compile the C Project. But adding one include for any kind of class or c++ stuff causes lots of errors while linking. unfortunately i need to include classes etc..

Btw. here's the error i get for this example:

```
Test.cpp:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()'
Test.cpp:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
Test.cpp:(.text$_ZN4TestD1Ev[Test::~Test()]+0x12): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
Test.cpp:(.eh_frame+0x6b): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
```

setting `-lstdc++` flag after (!) the flag for the library i get "only" these:

```
Test.cpp:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
Test.cpp:(.eh_frame+0x6b): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
```

Comment: Those references at the end look like references to functions provided by the C++ runtime (not the standard library, but the actual runtime stuff).  Try adding `-lc++` to the link command?  (Actually, g++ should take care of that...but eh.)

Comment: Doesn't work: `ld.exe: cannot find -lc++`.

Comment: As a test i removed all calls of functions from library; without them i can compile without errors. unfortunately i need these function calls :-/

Comment: If you have Test.cpp and Test.c, how do you create two different object files with different names?  With files `main.c`, `test1.c` and `Test.cpp`, on Red Hat (RHEL 5, x86_64), compiling the files separately and linking with `g++ -o main main.o test1.o Test.o` works fine.

Comment: I tested one file for both too, same result. But if it works for you, i'll check my compiler.

Comment: Looks like a bug in gcc - using a newer version solved all errors from above. However it's not working because of another problem (but i guess thats another question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem looks like a bug in MinGW GCC.

- Using **GCC 3.4.5**: *Error* as posted above
- Using **GCC 4.7.2**: *No Error*

Also make sure `-lstdc++` is the **last (!)** of your `-l` flags.

Answer (score 1):

Link your project with g++ rather than gcc.  G++ will take care of linking in the necessary c++ runtime implementation.

Comment: Using `g++` solves the reference to C++ std library problem, but i get a long list of errors too (please see my edit).